# Attributed text swift how to change color of unattributed text

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutableattributedstring

I try to make a night/day option for my app. I have a text like `"<font color="#aa2c2c">Red text</font>then back to normal "` . 
So I need red to stay red and change only unattributed color.

Here's what I try:

```
    text.enumerateAttributesInRange(NSRange(0..<text.length), options: []) { (attributes, range, _) -> Void in
        for (attribute, object) in attributes {
            NSLog("attr \(attribute) object \(object)")                
            }
        }
    }
```

So, log shows me something like "attr NSColor object UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1" or "attr NSStrokeColor object UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1". That seems to be that black text which I need to change to white.

So I put this in the loop:

```
        if object.name!.containsString("0 0 0 1"){
            text.setAttributes(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.whiteColor() , range: range)
        }
```

I'm not sure if it's the best decision, but I got error : Extra argument 'value' in call. 
What's wrong with this and what is the best way to substitute color of non-attributed text only?

Comment: There is no such method as `NSMutableAttributeString setAttributes:value:range:`. There is `setAttributes:range:` or `addAttribute:value:range:`, or `addAttributes:range:`.

Comment: Don't use the the description of the object to compare, the value should be a UIColor, just compare it.

Answer (score 4):

```
 let text = "We tried to make this app as most intuitive as possible for you. If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask us. For a detailed manual just click here."
 let linkTextWithColor = "click here"

 let range = (text as NSString).rangeOfString(linkTextWithColor)

 let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text)
 attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor() , range: range)

 self.helpText.attributedText = attributedString
```

or

```
myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSRange(location:2,length:4))
```